# How To hide destination url from preview of posts of social networking site like facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel-xmlapi

I'm using cpanel API for redirection from one domain to another, the facebook post shows the preview and url of the destination page(the redirected one), I want to hide the url of the redirected website from the facebook post but I couldn't find a method to do so.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^qwe$ "https\:\/\/www\.gangslangs\.com\/awkward\-moments\-which\-can\-make\-anyone\-feel\-the\-cringe\/\?utm_unique\=SY1X2g" [R=302,L]


/////API CALL
    $xmlapi = new xmlapi($ip);
    $xmlapi->password_auth($root, $root_pass);
    $xmlapi->set_port(2083);
    $xmlapi->set_debug(1);
    $xmlapi->set_output('json');
       $xmlapi->api2_query($account, "Email", "listpopswithdisk" );
    $domain = "subdomain2";
    $root=$_POST['url'];
    $dis="1";
    $random = randomString(6);
      $xmlapi->api1_query($account,'Mime', 'add_redirect', array($random,'permanent',$destination.'?utm_unique='.$random,'domain.in','0','0') );
```

redirect rules are  written properly in htaccess file but i want to hide the destination url in facebook post.

Comment: Facebook follows redirects.

Comment: Why do you want to hide the destination?

Comment: i want to hide the url of destination in the preview of facebook post